Siri is disabled, but there is Siri and Dictation icon the menu bar sometimes
Sonoma 14.5 on MacBook Pro M1
I have "Ask Siri" turned off, but sometimes, for about a second, near the Control Center icon, I see a little blue circle. Then, it quicky disappears.

If I click the Control Center icon when the blue circle is visible, the Control Icon pop-up window has this blue circle as well:

Why this happens?

Your location services are active when that arrow and blue circle shows up. This is a core function of control center.
You can manage this if you don’t like your current settings here: https://support.apple.com/guide/personal-safety/manage-location-services-settings-ips9bf20ad2f/web

Scroll to the bottom of the list of apps to reveal System Services, then click the Details button to see specific system services that use your location.

It’s perfectly normal and not at all a bug for that to be shown depending on what choices you prefer on macOS. Consider hiding that menu bar item if you want the feature and not the reminder.

Maybe you know how to disable just the icon in the menu bar without disabling location services themselves? This blue icon that appears-and-then-disappears-and-then-appears-again is just very annoying.

Why not use bartender to move that menu bar icon somewhere else or remove it? You can get to control center in several other ways.

Good idea, thanks.
